# Managed memory mapped file

Tags: c#, .net, memory-mapped-files

My problem is that I can not open the file. In another process or in the same process!

Code:

```
var path = @"c:\work\mmf.dat";
var map = "testmap123";
var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

if (fs.Length == 0)
{
    fs.SetLength(1024);
}

var sec = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
var mem = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fs, map, fs.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, sec, HandleInheritability.Inheritable, false);

// Problem here System.UnauthorizedAccessException

var tmp = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(map, MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
```

Comment: What is your error code?

Comment: 7FF8FFFB Access to the path is denied.

Comment: You took a shortcut on MemoryMappedFileSecurity.  Take another one, pass null instead.

Comment: Hans Passant, thank you. )))

Comment: @HansPassant I think last line gives an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var path = @"c:\diverse\mmf.dat";
var map = "testmap123";
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{

    if (fs.Length == 0)
    {
        fs.SetLength(1024);
    }
}
using (var mem = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(path, FileMode.Open, map, 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var tmp = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(map))
    {
        //work with tmp
    }
}
```